# SPARQL query RDF ontology

Tags: rdf, sparql

Im trying this sparql query, but Im having trouble to find out whats wrong. I would like to take all the receipes that has those ingredients or less. ie: 
receipe 1: Tomato
receipe 2: Tomato and salt
receipe 3: Tomato, salt, onion.

And I have the following query:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX rec:<http://www.receta.org#>

SELECT reduced ?r (count (?i) as ?cuantos) WHERE {

    ?x rdf:type rec:Receta .
    ?x rdfs:label ?r.

    filter not exists {
        ?x rec:Ingrediente ?i
        filter( ?i not in (rec:Tomato, rec:Salt) )
    }
}
GROUP BY ?r
```

I would to show only the first one. Not the second one and not the last one.

Its just an example but I actually want to do it with more that 3 receipes, lets say a huge database, I want to take the receipes that have less ingredients than tomato and salt for example. So any ideas of how can I fix my query to do so?

Im going to try to explain myself:

For example:

Lets say I have a huge database with hundreds recipes. Some of those are:
Recipe1: tomato and salt
Receipe2: Onion and meat
Receipe3: Tomato and vinegar
Receipe4: chocolate and milk

And in my query I say that I want the recipes with tomato, salt and vinegar. So in that case I would like to get the Recipe1 and the Recipe3, because the recipe1 has tomato and salt and the recipe3 has tomato and vinegar, one ingredient less than what I say. Lets say now that I add more recipes:

Recipe4: Tomato
Recipe5: Salt 
Recipe6: Tomato, vinegar, salt and onion
Recipe6: Tomato, vinegar, salt

If I execute my query again I would like to have the recipe1, recipe3, recipe4 and recipe5. Cause 
those recipes are those that has those ingredients or less. I dont want to have the recipe6 cause has more ingredients than what I asked and not even the recipe7.

Thank you!!!

Comment: If you want recipes that have those ingredients or less, shouldn't you include recipe number 2, since it only includes tomato and salt?

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you're looking for?   It sounds like you're asking for recipes whose ingredients are a subset of what you've specified, but if that's the case, then why don't you want the second recipe?

Comment: OP posted as an answer (but should have posted as a comment): " put that as an example but I actually want to do it with more that 3 receipes, lets say a huge database, I want to take the receipes that have less ingredients than tomato and salt for example. Understand?"

Comment: (1) You wrote recipe6 twice, so I assume you meant recipe7 teh second time.  (2)  It's probably better to post updates and clarifications in the question (with the edit button) instead of the comments.  (3) Thank you for the updates.  (4) Assuming that that recipe7 is "Tomato, vinegar, salt". why do you *not* want recipe7?  It sounds like you don't want "those ingredients or less", but *strictly less* than the specified ingredients.

Comment: Is this correct:  You want to specify a set S of ingredients and return recipes whose ingredients are a *proper*  subset of S?

Comment: It's really much better to provide some sample data that we can work with with actual SPARQL processing tools.  It's rather inconvenient if you can't provide us with data that we can work with.  Based on your clarifications, I've updated my answer, and you can see how it's not hard at all to come up with some sample data to test an approach on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're trying to specify a set of ingredients, and then select the recipes whose ingredients are a property subset of that set of ingredients (or maybe those whose ingredients are just a subset;  the examples in your question don't make this clear).  At any rate, rather than writing examples out in natural language where it's easy to make mistakes, it's better to provide data we can work with, and in this case it's not hard at all to do that.  For instance, here's a small Turtle file with nine recipes, each of which has some ingredients:

```
@prefix : <urn:ex:> .

:recipe1 :ingredient :tomato, :salt .
:recipe2 :ingredient :onion, :meat .
:recipe3 :ingredient :tomato, :vinegar .
:recipe4 :ingredient :chocolate, :milk .
:recipe5 :ingredient :tomato .
:recipe6 :ingredient :salt .
:recipe7 :ingredient :tomato, :vinegar, :salt, :onion .
:recipe8 :ingredient :tomato, :vinegar, :salt .
:recipe9 :ingredient :vinegar, :salt .
```

Now, we can write a query that retrieves recipes all of whose ingredients are in a specified set, and keeps only those that have less than (or less than or equal to) some specific number of distinct ingredients.  (You don't have to include the **group_concat** stuff;  I just did that to get an ingredient list for each recipe.)

```sql
prefix : <urn:ex:>

select ?recipe (group_concat(?ingredient;separator=', ') as ?ingredients) {
  ?recipe :ingredient ?ingredient
  filter not exists {
    ?recipe :ingredient ?other_ingredient
    filter( ?other_ingredient not in ( :salt, :tomato, :vinegar ) )
  }
}
group by ?recipe
having (count(distinct ?ingredient) < 3)
```

```
----------------------------------------------
| recipe   | ingredients                     |
==============================================
| :recipe9 | "urn:ex:salt, urn:ex:vinegar"   |
| :recipe5 | "urn:ex:tomato"                 |
| :recipe6 | "urn:ex:salt"                   |
| :recipe3 | "urn:ex:tomato, urn:ex:vinegar" |
| :recipe1 | "urn:ex:tomato, urn:ex:salt"    |
----------------------------------------------
```

If you wanted to allow recipes with all three ingredients, you could just change the line

```sql
having (count(distinct ?ingredient) < 3)
```

to either of:

```sql
having (count(distinct ?ingredient) <= 3)
```

```sql
having (count(distinct ?ingredient) < 4)
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I want, but I want to order it by amount of ingredients. So I would like to have: Receipe5, receipe6. receipe9, receipe3, receipe1. Sorry for the misunderstood. thank you

Comment: I didn't see any mention of ordering in the question, but it's just a matter of adding `order by count(distinct ?ingredient)`.  [order by](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#modOrderBy) is clearly described in the specification.